# Impersonate Problem

Tags: impersonation

We are running a application which will write files into another machine using Impersonate  through WebService .But we are not able to write those files.We dont know how to grant permission to access the folder.

Help me.

Comment: A few environmental variables would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but I think you simply need to right-click the directory you wish to grant the webservice rights to and go to the Security tab and then add the account the service will be running under to the allow list.

For example, we would have like asp.net@yourlocationname.local in my workplace.
Hopefully it is as simple as that.